# How to edit an element attribute within the html through Selenium and Python?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So my problem is that i need to edit this image source in selenium, but it doesn't have id or class.

```
<div id="mbr-content">
            <div class="nope" some random stuff>
    <script>
    </script>

        <div class="mbr-image-container">
            <div class="mbr-image-wrapper">
                <div class="mbr-image">
                    <img src="this source need to modify" alt="app_image">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    #Html continues here
```

I just in some reason cant figure this one out.

I know that I need to use this command but not sure what shut I putt inside as script.

```
driver.execute_script("something here")
```

Using python-3.7

Comment: *"I have tried somethings..."* which *"things"* exactly?

Comment: That is hard to say because it's been couple weeks last time I tried this and I was close to get it work. If remember them I will edit them over there.

Comment: You mean say changing some HTML attribute using `execute_script` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript required to set the `src` attribute of your `<img>` element is:

```
document.querySelector(".mbr-image > img").src="whatver you want";
```

So, you can try below solution:

```
js = 'document.querySelector(".mbr-image > img").src="whatver you want";'
driver.execute_script(js)
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to edit the `src` attribute of the desired element you can use the following solution:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mbr-image-container']/div[@class='mbr-image-wrapper']/div[@class='mbr-image']/img[@alt='app_image']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('src','something here')", element)
```